# mod rewrite from .php to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Id like to forward links like

https://server.com/checkAvailability to https://server.com/api/checkAvailability.php

I tried the following in .htaccess but it did not work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ ./api/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Your rules appear almost fine. Just place this code into `api/.htaccess` and last line should be `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested with your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ api/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: @ryanramsumair, could you please do let me know which example/sample url you are hitting and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: im getting 404 Error Not Found when i try to access 

https://server.com/checkAvailability and the file resides on https://server.com/api/checkAvailability.php

Comment: @ryanramsumair, OK, could you please try changing rule FROM `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f` TO `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/$1\.php -f` once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: still 404 with last change, if i use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]  https://server.com/api/checkAvailability is executed but when i write RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ api/$1.php [L]  and use  server.com/checkAvailability same 404 error

Comment: @ryanramsumair, ok could you please do let me know where is your htaccess file exist(samples/examples) and where is the path of your documents? Rules look fine to me only thing we need to adjust the paths here.

Comment: htaccess is in /var/www/server.com/public_html directory and checkAvailability.php in /var/www/server.com/public_html/api directory. This is the content of the siteenabled apache2 , im not sure if this is causing any conflict RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.server.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =server.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/server.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: @ryanramsumair, ohh but I can't see my rules in your htaccess file? Can you please confirm they are there once please.

Comment: yes in .htaccess                                                                                                     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ api/$1.php [L]

Comment: @ryanramsumair, ok could you please try to place your htaccess file into `/var/www/server.com/public_html/api` path once? I am considering that your files are present there.

Comment: same 404, ill play around with settings tomorrow , thanks for the help

Comment: @ryanramsumair, I believe this would have worked if your php files are present in `public_html/api` folder, can you try changing `[L]` TO `[R=301,L]` once in my rules to see what it shows you which url in your browser, will give us some clue what's going on.